# Can we get sms sent and delivered status from inside of a Broadcast Receiver in Android.

Tags: android

Can we get sms sent and delivered status from inside of a Broadcast Receiver in Android. I can send sms from my receiver but I don't know how to get the status inside my receiver. I have checked a lots of example but none is for getting status inside receiver. I know there are lots of genius. Please help me out with a small example. It is my requirement to send sms from receiver class and sent a notification based on the sms status. 
I thank in advance for your help.

Comment: refer http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/smsmessage-delivery-in-android-with.html

Comment: above link is again for getting the status inside the activity not from inside the BroadcastReceiver class. My requirement is to get the status inside receiver class not from activity. The problem is I can't register another receiver inside broadcast receiver class. Please give me some working code that I can use to get status INSIDE my receiver class. Thanks again for your help in advance.